# MediaWiki rewrite url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I have made an installation in a Linux Debian of MediaWiki version 1.31 with Apache. I installed the installation in the path `/var/www/html/wiki`. All right, because when I open the browser and put `http://<ip_server>/wiki`, it correctly enters my MediaWiki installation.

What I now want is to redirect or rewrite `http://<ip_server>/wiki` to `http://<ip_server>/` so that if I put in the browser `http://<ip_server>/` it will redirect me to my MediaWiki installation.

Comment: It is not a programming question. Try to ask on AskUbuntu or similar sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Short URLs documentation at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

Basically, you need to create a file called `.htaccess` in `/var/www/html/` with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

And add this line to your LocalSettings.php file:

```
$wgArticlePath = "/$1";
```

**Note:** The documentation suggests that you avoid using short URLs that are on the server root (like `http://<ip_server>/`) because things get complicated when you have pages named `Images`, `Docs`, `Extensions`, etc.